# get url parameter query via injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

need direct access to an object that can reveal information about the query parameter passed.

Would prefer a way to get hold of an object just like you could do with injector for an $http object

```
var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
```

what's the most direct/short/concise/eloquent way to get the query variables without going through a controller.

Alternatively other options please.

Comment: window.location.search should do the trick, without any framework dependencies.

Comment: yeah, that's good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here is an Example to get query parameter
In app.js  for example
.when('/catagory/:catagoryid/:catagoryname',
            {

                templateUrl:'partials/bookOfParticularCatagory.html',
                controller:'bookOfParticularCatagoryController'


            })


In controller
app.controller("bookOfParticularCatagoryController",function($routeParams,$scope,$http){

     $scope.catagoryid=  $routeParams.catagoryid;
     $scope.catagoryname= $routeParams.catagoryname;
```